# Cannot invoke PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions after upgrade to swift 1.2 and xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I updated to XCode 6.3 (and there fore Swift 1.2 with it) and all hell broke loose. So many errors all over the project so  Iam going to attempt to understand them one by one. Here's one I fixed myself but just by guessing. Can someone explain what happened here.

Here is the code showing the error (note that this was actually working before the update)

[image]

This is how I fixed it, but I don't understand what happened here????

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            println("User cancelled the Facebook Login")
        } else if user!.isNew{
            println("New User signed up using Facebook")
        } else {
            println("User logged in through facebook")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("launchmenu", sender: self)

        }
    })
```